# Is maxOccurs="unbounded" insecure in XSD?

Tags: xml, security, xsd

I have an XML Schema where I found `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.  When googling I found that it's not the secure way of writing XML schema and saw the recommendation to use specific number there instead of unbound. But the problem is I do not have that specific reasonable number to use there so is there any way to make it secure when I do not have a specific number to set there.

```
<sequence>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Application" 
             nillable="true" type="impl:Application"/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 4):

**No.** There's nothing inherently wrong with using `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in XSD.

Whatever (uncited) reference you've read may have been motivated by wanting to avoid buffer overruns or some other exploitation of some weakness of some particular XML software.  Further speculation is worthless; either provide a specific reference whose credibility can be assessed, or withdraw your concern as completely unfounded.

Comment: This shows up on fortify scans https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.config.xml.weak_xml_schema_unbounded_occurrences

Comment: @Alao: Thank you for pointing out a possible source for OP's security concern.  That report, as anticipated, merely provides weak guidance that should neither be overgeneralized nor used blindly to impose artificial occurrence restrictions in the name of unsubstantiated "security" concerns that could better be addressed at lower levels of abstraction than XSD.

Comment: I agree but I'm currently working with a security group in the government that takes these fortify findings as gospel.  I'm actually going to use part of your response as a justification that this is not a security concern but more of a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There may be systems that you want to protect from DDoS attacks by limiting the amount of data that can be sent to them. I don't think XML Schema is the right technology for doing that.

Apart from anything else, using finite maxOccurs values is quite insufficient. You would also need, for example, to limit the number of comments that can appear between the elements, and there is no way XML Schema can be used to limit comments or processing instructions.

If you want to limit the size of incoming documents, you need a different (and probably much simpler) kind of defence.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this depends entirely on the system you are building. If you have some reason to believe that the implementing system would somehow suffer from an unbounded number of "application"-elements (whatever that means?), then perhaps it may be an issue - but there is nothing inherently wrong with it in itself.

Remember that the XSD is where you define certain rules for your system; in some instances certain rules may be appropriate, in other situations, they may be dangerous. Based on the limited info in your question though, I can't see any specific reason to worry (again: You need think through what the practical consequences for the implementing system will be!).